# Connection property has not been initialized while running application from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have one intranet based application.I have set windows authentication for it in `Web.config` as well as from IIS settings.

While running my application through the source code, it works fine but while running from directly IIS then its giving me:

> "Connection property has not been initialized"

Comment: And in what *context* is it giving that? what code are you executing there?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is IIS websites runs with different account - usually it's NETWORK SERVICE